# Error updating Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

So my issue seems to be coming from an old Gemfile (from a past project) that still seems to by linked to an old Gemfile. What I am trying to do is update the current information stored with new PATHS for installation and execution.

I am working on a new project but continue to run into errors and hope to update the information. When I run GEM ENV the results print paths to a different directory other than the info stored in my .bash_profile & .gemrc:

Example:

$ gem env
Failed to load /Users/brainz/.gemrc

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/brainz/dev/oldfile/local/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/brainz/dev/oldfile/local/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/brainz/dev/csbox/local/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

This is what I would like my -> .gemrc file:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
gemhome: /home/brainz/.gems
gempath:
- /home/brainz/.gems
- usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0
:benchmark: false
:update_sources: true
:verbose: false
:backtrace: false
:sources
- http://gems.rubyforge.org/
:bulk_threshold: 1000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have hit a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your Gemfile.lock then hit bundle update

Answer (score -1):

have you tried deleting your `Gemfile.lock` file and `bundle install` again

Comment: no it did not. now I'm receiving the issue ' failed to load .gemrc '